# Isolate modules within one F# project using folders - is it possible?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2017

I like the way F# requires to organize files and code in order of dependency because it discourages mindless coupling.

I have flat list of source files atm (simplified):

```
Common.fs
Workflow1.fs
Workflow2.fs
```

And want to go one step beyond. First, organize files like this (VS 2017 can't move folders up and down, one needs to edit .fsproj but it is different story - at least it is possible):

```
Common.fs
Workflow1\Impl1.fs
Workflow2\Impl2.fs
```

I expected Impl1.fs and Impl2.fs to be fully isolated from each other because their folders are not in parent/child relationship, but Impl2.fs can easily see types and functions from Impl1.fs: just open module and they are available

Are there any techniques to keep them isolated? It's possible to split the project in three however I prefer to keep DLL as a unit of deployment: workflows are small and ideally I want to avoid to have many tiny DLL files.

Comment: The only piece missing from your question is the fact that you can make some of the members of your module private. If Impl1.fs is the only module, then that provides the isolation you are looking for. Otherwise, I think you have covered all the possibilities, and the answer to your question is "no."

Comment: Sure I use private modifier whenever I can. Workflows still expose some types to external world (a C# client) and hence to each other (more precise - only Impl2 can see Impl1), it's just a perfectionist in me wanted to fully isolate them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have a good understanding of what your options are. You are not missing anything else. Consequently, the answer to your question is, "no."

Answer (score 2):

You can't isolate the folders that way, as far as I know.  However, if you want to keep them isolated at compile time but deployable as a single unit, you can create separate projects and use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) or [ILMerge](https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge) to combine the assemblies post-compilation.